# MySQL find in database where value in array in JSON is BETWEEN something

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have database

| user | info |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {"messages": [{"user_to": 1, "timestamp": 1663000000}, {"user_to": 2, "timestamp": 1662000000}]} |
| 1 | {"messages": [{"user_to": 0, "timestamp": 1661000000}, {"user_to": 2, "timestamp": 1660000000}]} |
| 2 | {"messages": []} |

And I want to select all users who sent messages between timestamp 1662000000 and 1663000000 (any amount of messages, not all of them)

I don't have external table of messages, so I can't select from there

Comment: Parse using [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) then check.

Comment: Is each message only have two timestamp?

Comment: Each message have only one timestamp, in example user sent two messages with timestamps 1663000000 and 1662000000

Comment: Does each "messages" array contains not more than two elements with separate message timestamps? Or maybe there exists some upper limit other than 2?

Comment: You say you don't have a messages table, but do you control that? Because this should really be replaced by a messages table if you are going to use a relational database.

Comment: There may be any amount of messages

Comment: @HeyThereAmI, Out of curiosity, why did you decide to use JSON for the array of messages? If you stored messages in a separate table with one message per row, querying it would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **MySQL v8.0.x**, you can utilize `JSON_TABLE` to create a `JSON` formatted table in a subquery. Then, select your `DISTINCT` users using your timestamp in a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.`user` FROM (
      SELECT `user`, a.*
      FROM `sample_table`, 
      JSON_TABLE(`info`,'$'
           COLUMNS (
              NESTED PATH '$.messages[*]'
                COLUMNS (
                  `user_to` int(11)  PATH '$.user_to',
                  `timestamp` int(40) PATH '$.timestamp')
                   )
                ) a
              ) b
WHERE b.`timestamp` BETWEEN 1662000000 AND 1663000000
ORDER BY b.`user` ASC
```

**Input:**

| user | info |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {"messages": [{"user_to": 1, "timestamp": 1663000000}, {"user_to": 2, "timestamp": 1662000000}]} |
| 1 | {"messages": [{"user_to": 0, "timestamp": 1661000000}, {"user_to": 2, "timestamp": 1660000000}]} |
| 2 | {"messages": []} |
| 3 | {"messages": [{"user_to": 0, "timestamp": 1662000000}, {"user_to": 2, "timestamp": 1661000000}, {"user_to": 2, "timestamp": 1660000000}, {"user_to": 2, "timestamp": 1663000000}]} |

**Output:**

| user |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 3 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qf1CsoTw)